# Unable connect to a HTTP URL in Android 10

Tags: android, http, https, retrofit2, socket-timeout-exception

I am using a `http://something` API for the login process. But could't get a hit on API in Android 10. For rest of the version, the API is working fine.
First of all, I was getting *SocketTimeoutException*. Then I tried following solutions.

1) Added below attribute to `<application>` in Manifest.

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

Result: Still getting *SocketTimeoutException*.

2) Then I added `networkSecurityConfig`:

```
<network-security-config>
<domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">project.dev.company:6001/</domain>
    <trust-anchors>
        <certificates src="system"/>
    </trust-anchors>
</domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Result : *UnknownServiceException : CLEARTEXT communication to project.dev.company:6001/ is not permitted by network security policy.*

3) Also tried permitting CLEARTEXT in `<base-config>`. Still getting *SocketTimeoutException*.

How can I permit my app to access a HTTP connection from Android 10? I am using Retrofit2 for network calling.

Comment: have you add internet permission inside manifest?

Comment: Yes. Can login from any other Android versions, except version 10.

Comment: you are using retrofit .arent you?

Comment: @rajkavadia Yes, I am using retrofit2.

Comment: "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
  Accept: "application/json"

Comment: add these inside headers

Comment: I have this question too. if you found the answer please tell me how to solve this

Answer (score 5):

Use this codes in your xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
   <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
      <domain includeSubdomains="true">project.dev.company</domain>
   </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

and use this codes in manifest:

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_configuration"
```

dont need any "/" and port in domain,just use like me

Edited:

you can use IP of your api host,like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
      <domain includeSubdomains="true">192.168.1.1</domain>
   </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

Comment: now i certainly say this: your domain is not correct, take a look to it.and check edit

Comment: If I use IP, it works just by adding `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`.

Comment: Partially. By following your solution I get SocketTimeOutException again. Sorry, Though I upvoted, I cannot mark the answer accepted just about now because it may create confusion in future.

Comment: cleartextTrafficPermitted="true" on my 2 domains restored URLConnection connectivity for me, but... Isn't it unsafe to do so? Is it a good practice?